# how to know mobile log in or regular log in?

Tags: java, gwt, user-agent

how to know whether an user log in into my application through mobile or PC?how we can track him?is there any mechanism in java to find out which device is using to log in?

Comment: You need to check user agent. See http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used java code to get the userAgent:

```
private String UserAgent = Navigator.getUserAgent()
```

Answer (score 1):

Could use a simply JNSI to get it eg.

```
 private native String getUserAgent() /*-{
        return navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    }-*/;
```